# how to change text inside anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to change the text 'save' to 'edit' in this html code using jquery

```
<a id="personalSave" href="#" class="SaveText"> 
<span class="FloatLeft">&lsaquo;</span>
save
<span class="FloatRight">&rsaquo;</span>
</a>
```

i tried changing the text(**save** between the spans ) using

```
$('#personalSave').innerText = "edit";
```

but its not working..

Comment: Change it when what? Click on link or what? Improve your question please...

Comment: Mhm... What? Can you please explain better?

Comment: Use `$('#personalSave').text('edit')` instead...

Comment: @LightStyle dat did the trick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what worked for me

```
$('#personalSave').text('edit');
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your text also in a span:

```
<a id="personalSave" href="#" class="SaveText"> 
    <span class="FloatLeft">&lsaquo;</span>
    <span class='txt'>save</span>
    <span class="FloatRight">&rsaquo;</span>
</a>
```

Now you can select it:

```
$('#personalSave .txt').text("edit");
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work but it's probably not the best way to do it:

```
$("#personalSave").text($("#personalSave").text().replace("save", "edit"));
```

Better wrap the text in a span and change that.